# How do I make the select2 search box "inline"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am migrating from Twitter's typeahead.js to select2.

One thing I really like about typeahead.js is how the selected value and the search box appear in the same field. You can try it out [here](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/).

I would like to achieve the same in select2. You'll notice that in select2 the "currently selected value" is a different place than the search box.

[image: Picture here]

How do I make it so that it is the same element?

Comment: Note: I want to do this using select2 `single` dropdown, not `multiple`.

Comment: Have you looked into implementing a custom selectionAdapter with such ability? You could start with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0z40mk63/) - it works very bad, but at least gives an idea on where to start

Comment: Have you figured out the way?

Comment: Have you figured out the way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

At least now is always inline...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    Inline:
    <select>
      <option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
      <option value="Burger">Burger</option>
      <option value="Sugar">Sugar</option>
    </select>
    indeed!
```

But! If you use bootstrap you have to make the form inline. Just add the class `form-inline` to the form. I had to do that to get it inline...

Answer (score 0):

Woe from the mind, everything is much simpler

```
.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--below {
  position: relative;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
  position: absolute;
  top: -27px;
  border: 0px !important;
  width: 94%;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field:focus-visible {
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You Have Used **Multiple** Html Attributes Used:

For Example:
Using For bootstrap Css and Bootstrap Script

Using For Bootstrap Select Css And Script

Using For Latest query Version

write your Drop down Code

```html
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple>
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar</option>
</select>
```

For example:

```html
   
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <select class="selectpicker"  multiple>
      <option data-tokens="Pizza">Pizza</option>
      <option data-tokens="Burger">Burger</option>
      <option data-tokens="Sugar">Sugar</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score -3):

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple>
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar</option>
</select>
```

Try Code:

Comment: A little explanation can go a long way in creating a helpful answer - [answer]

Comment: i have write a code only one dropdown other wise  link to  bootsrtap css

Comment: You Have Execute Snippet

Comment: This answer doesn't explain anything